# Allow placing caret only on first position in title input field

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions

Currently, when creating a question, there is a placeholder in the title field. But when focusing into this field the placeholder doesn't disappear, like it normally does.

I can imagine that this is done, a) so the message is still visible while you think about your question title (so it may have more influence) and b) so autofocus can be used.

But what quite irritates me, is that you can place the caret at any place of this placeholder, making it look like a normal text. This normally causes me to mark all the text and delete it.

So, my feature request: Could the caret be always placed on the first position in the title? That way the placeholder text would still be visible, but it wouldn't feel like a real text.

Comment: No, "edit-field-overlayed" is correct. Either way, the whole placeholder thing has been reworked (this change will be deployed shortly), so that won't be an issue anymore.

Comment: @balpha: Uhm, yes, you are obviously right. I saw that it was different from what's in the HTML source and thought it was a typo. Sorry for that.

Comment: No problem -- it's great to see when people care enough to start debugging themselves :)

Answer (score 2):

As I hinted at in the comment on your question, the placeholder functionality has changed, so it's not possible to interact with it (like with normal text) anymore.